# How can I use a UIPickerView in my settings.bundle like how the 'nike+ ipod' app does it?

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview, settings.bundle

I can't see how this is possible from the documentation but here nike is doing it in their app so there must be a way.

[image: Nike + iPod custom UIPickerView]

Comment: I'm pretty sure Nike is getting some preferential treatment from Apple here. Well, Apple wrote the whole thing AFAIK, so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible unfortunately. Apple developed it for Nike, so they used tricks of their own to do it. It might actually be possible, but it's certainly undocumented if possible. Impossible for an App Store app. Let us know if you figure out a way to do it even if it's undocumented.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the library [InAppSettingsKit](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit), you can have a setting that uses a custom subview (a custom UIViewController) to display the choice to the user. So all you have to do is to create a custom view controller that looks just the one in your picture (it's basically just a UITableView and a UIPickerView).

In the example app that comes along with InAppSettingsKit, there is an example on how to use a custom subview.